# Не работает "for in" после функций "max", "min"

Tags: python, циклы, max, min

```
p1 = int (1723.9) #Сюда передаются данные
p2 = int (2094.2) #через переменные
pp1 = max(p1,p2)+1
pp2 = min(p1,p2)
print (f'max: {pp1}\nmin: {pp2}')

for i in range(pp1,pp2):
    print (i)
```

Если передавать в "range" "p1" и "p2" то всё работает.
Но почему оно не работает после min и max!?
Пробовал так:

```
pp1 = int(max(p1,p2))+1
pp2 = int(min(p1,p2))
```

Comment: Напиши какие числа у тебя в pp1 и pp2 и что ты ждёшь от range (pp1, pp2) в этом случае

Comment: pp1 и pp2 принимают максимальное и минимальное значение. P1 и p2 это пользовательский инпут через телеграм бота. Цикл упростил до принта за отсутствием необходимости показывать всё остальное, т.к. оно работает

Answer (score 0):

print(pp1,pp2)
сделайте принт, и вы все поймете

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Он уже присутствует в 5 строчке.

Comment: дело в том что я хотел, что бы он сам понял в чем проблема. натолкнуть так сказать на правильную дорогу.

Answer (score 0):

Поменял местами pp1 и pp2 и все заработало

```
for i in range(pp2,pp1):
```

Comment: Ну да, естественно минимум меньше, чем максимум и надо от минимума до максимума `range` делать